# Module get_url results filter

Tags: ansible

I want to parse specific output from `get_url` when I pass a list of URLs as a parameter.

I know I can get output to the level of `{{ get_url_results1.results }}`

BUT, I'm having trouble parsing output below the "results" level.

Thanks in advance :-)

Various combinations of filters and regex

```
- name: "Verify: MY_FILE_LIST was passed as parameter"
  local_action: 
    module: shell
      echo "{{ lookup('env','MY_FILE_LIST') }}"
  register: echo_my_file_list
  failed_when: echo_my_file_list.stdout ==""
- debug:
    msg: "{{ echo_my_file_list.stdout.split('\n') }}"  

- name: "Get Release Files from Artifactory"
  local_action: 
    module: get_url 
    url: "{{ item }}" 
    dest: "{{ lookup('env','WORKSPACE') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes 
    url_username: "{{ lookup('env','MY_USERID') }}"
    url_password: "{{ lookup('env','MY_PASSWORD') }}"
    validate_certs: no      
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
  - "{{ echo_my_file_list.stdout_lines }}"   
  register: get_url_results1
- name: "DEBUG: Get Release Files from Artifactory"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ get_url_results1 }}"
```

I want to output to only the following from the "module: get_url" for each file I retrieve.

```
"checksum_dest": "06f787da1b7b4c0bb0bb58bd90493165a96ea4ff",
"checksum_src": "06f787da1b7b4c0bb0bb58bd90493165a96ea4ff",
```

Comment: Sorry, the Ansible format was mangled

Comment: Hi DevOps Ninja, welcome to SO. You have failed to say what you have already tried, as SO is not a "write code for me" website

Comment: I answered my own question but if anyone has an alternate solution, it would be greatly appreciate

Comment: Matt:  Your answer is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works:

```
- name: "DEBUG: Get Release Files from Artifactory"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "Checksum of files from source:"
      - "{{ get_url_results.results | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
      - "{{ get_url_results.results | map(attribute='md5sum') | list }}"
```